# PHP Filtering Multidimensional Array

Tags: php, json, input, multidimensional-array, filter

I have a large, multidimensional array echoed from a JSON file. I need to be able to filter it based on a search term.

```
Array
(
    [timeline] => Array
        (
            [type] => default
            [date] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [startDate] => 2014
                            [endDate] => 
                            [headline] => AA
                            [text] => Lorem Ipsum
                            [asset] => Array
                                (
                                    [media] => IMAGE_URL
                                    [thumbnail] => 
                                    [credit] => Public Domain, Wikimedia Commons
                                    [caption] => CAPTION_TITLE
                                )

                        )
//...and so on
```

I need to be able to filter for both the `text` and `headline` keys, and return values containing only a given string.

Comment: So you need to search through a multidimensional array, what have you tried? Have you googled it, I'm sure you're not the first one looking to search through an array.

Comment: I have tried using several basic array_filter functions, but cannot come up with anything that will work for a multidimensional array. I am new to PHP and was looking for a solution more tailored to this particular array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```
foreach($array['timeline']['date'] as $entry){
   if(strpos($entry['headline'],$needle) === false || strpos($entry['text'],$needle) === false){
      // nicht gefunden
    }else{
      // gefunden
    }
}
```

it's important to use === as the result could be false or 0 if the needle is int he beginning of the string. With == that would be the same.

Comment: This helps, but it needs to retain the original structure of the array: 

Array
(
    [timeline] => Array
        (
            [type] => default
            [date] => Array
                (       
                   //only return subarrays that contain matching term

Comment: It still has the same strucktur but only looks as a part of the array. If you want to access parts of the array higher in the hirarchy you can work with keys: `foreach($array as $key => $entry){}`. You might need to splith the loop to get keys for different levels of your array.